# pymongo update didnt work

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Can someone help me with this, I can't change some values from the mongodb.

This is the "structure":

```
'nombreLinea': nombreLinea,
'barra':
        { 'nombre': 
            { 
                'nombre_PLP': nombreBarraPLP,
                'nombre_PET': nombreBarraPET, 
                'nombre_OSE': nombreBarraOSE,
            }
        }, 
    'generador': 
        [{
            'nombre': 
                { 
                    'nombre_PLP': nombreGeneradorPLP,
                    'nombre_PET': nombreGeneradorPET,
                    'nombre_OSE': nombreGeneradorOSE,
                }
         }]
```

What Im trying to do is:

```
def actualizarMongo(nombreLineaa, nombreBarraPLP, nombreGeneradorPET, nombreBarraPLPGen):  
    if nombreBarraPLP == nombreBarraPLPGen:  
        db.linea.update(
            {
                "nombreLinea": nombreLineaa,  
                "barra.nombre.nombreBarraPLP": nombreBarraPLPGen  
            },  
            {'$set': { 
                "generador.nombre.nombre_PET": nombreGeneradorPET  
            }})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This part of your query `"barra.nombre.nombreBarraPLP"` doesn't match your document's structure.

Also, according to the structure, `generador` is an array of documents, so you will need to include the array element in the update:

`{'$set':{"generador.0.nombre.nombre_PET": nombreGeneradorPET }`

Answer (score 0):

this part of your code is unsuitable:

```
{'$set':{"generador.nombre.nombre_PET": nombreGeneradorPET }}
```

this is a document actually in an array.so try to read this document: [update document in an array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array)

hope it can help you.